# No view found for id ...(com.example....:id/notesFragment) for fragment NotesFragment

Tags: android

I want to switch from activity to fragment after clicking the button.application crashes when button is clicked and gives this error

For transition I wrote it in acitvity

```
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.notesFragment,new NotesFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

fragment_notes.xml

i gave id as "noteFragment"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Fragments.NotesFragment"
    android:background="@color/mainDarkBlue"
    android:id="@+id/notesFragment">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:fabSize="auto"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/rossyBrown"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_add_note"
            android:id="@+id/button_fab"/>
      ...
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>  
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml file where btnSave is available ?

Comment: where click listener is in activity

Comment: fragment_notes.xml is your activity layout or the fragments layout which you are trying to replace? You should have a container inside your activity and put that ID in fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,new NotesFragment());

Comment: yes put that xml file

Comment: Main activity has a frame layout for fragment

Comment: @xyz then check the id of framelayout and replace it with that id

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your parent class id to inflate your fragment not your fragment name itself

```
 btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.parentLayoutId, new NotesFragment()); 
            //Change R.id.notesFragment to your parent class main layout id
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Something Like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnRedirectFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Default Fragment" />


    <!--  Frame Layout for placing Fragments  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: same result, no view found for id .. for parentId

Comment: now try with above .xml file and change R.id.parentLayoutId to R.id.fragmentContainer

Comment: I have frame layout in main activity xml  and frame layout have id as content_area. 

 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_area,new NotesFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: I wrote it NoteActivty

Comment: It did not. instead I set the default fragment in the activity as notes fragment.
fragment opened when I switch between activities